# Template argument missing for boolean operator?

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, circular-list

I'm currently creating a circular doubly-linked list as exercise. The exercise is templating the damn thing, which is proving to be quite a pain. After many, many, many error-removals I get more errors. I'd laugh at that, but I'm quite tired and exhausted now.

```
Node.h

template<class T>
class Node
{
public:
    Node(T val) : data(val), next(0), prev(0) {}
    Node(T val, Node *next, Node *prev) : data(val), next(next), prev(prev) {}
    Node() : data(0), next(0), prev(0) {}
    ~Node()
    {}

    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
    T data;
};
```

.

```
LinkedList.h // Superclass

    #ifndef _LINKEDLIST_H_
#define _LINKEDLIST_H_

#include "Node.h"

enum Direction
{
    Forward,
    Backward
};

template<class T>
class LinkedList
{
public: 
    virtual void push_back(T data) = 0;
    virtual void push_front(T data) = 0;

    virtual void pop_back() = 0;
    virtual void pop_front() = 0;

    virtual void insert_before(T data, int index) = 0;
    virtual void insert_after(T data, int index) = 0;

    virtual void pop_before() = 0;
    virtual void pop_after() = 0;

    virtual void display(Direction direction = Forward) = 0;
    virtual int  length() const = 0;

    virtual T operator[](int index) = 0;
    virtual Node<T> *operator()(T data) = 0; 
};

#endif
```

.

```
CDLinkedList.h // Circular Doubly-Linked List

template<class T>
class CDLinkedList : public LinkedList<T>
{
public:
    /* Functions go here */
Node<T> *operator()(T data)
{
    Node<T> *temp = head;
    for( int i(0); 
          i < length()-1 && temp->data != data; 
          ++i, temp = temp->next )
        continue;

    if( temp->data == data )
        return temp;
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: Element not found." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
}

void display(Direction direction = Forward)
{
    std::ostream_iterator<T> oIter(std::cout, " ");
    if( direction == Forward )
    {
        Node<T> *temp = head;
        for( int i(0); i < length(); ++i, temp = temp->next )
            oIter = temp->data;
    }
    else
    {
        Node<T> *temp = tail;
        for( int i(0); i < length(); ++i, temp = temp->prev )
            oIter = temp->data;
    }
}
```

.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    using std::cin;
    using std::string;

    CDLinkedList<std::string> list;
    list.push_back("Hello");
    list.push_back(",");
    list.push_back("World.");
    cout << "Displaying normally..." << endl;
    list.display();
    cout << "Displaying backwards..." << endl;
    list.display(::Direction::Backward);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The templates work with int as input, but not with string, which is what I'm currently trying to get to work.

The last function `Node *operator()(T data)` is my current problem child. The error I get is:

`error C2784: 'bool std::operator !=(const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &' from 'std::string'`

What's wrong here?

Comment: You should probably give some more info. Like, where are you passing in a std::vector<T>? And to what exactly?

Comment: Added the call from main() to the function as well as the input and the working input(ints work)

Comment: There's something missing here. `CDLinkedList` doesn't appear to have a `display` member function, and where's `operator()` being called from?

Comment: I didn't add the display function since I didn't think that was a problem. However, now that you mention it, I didn't use the () operator. What I have shown in main is what I have written in my program. Odd. Added the display function.

Comment: Your code does not use `std::vector` and does not use `CDLinkedList::operator()`. Yet you complain about problems related to the two. Apparently, you code is fake. Post real code.

Comment: @AndreyT: I assure you, it is not fake. All I can do is post the rest of the code, but I don't think it would add much more. Edit: Added some rest of the code.

Comment: When posting questions, be sure to a) use real code, b) provide the error messages *with* the line where the compiler is identifying the error and c) make sure that that line is present in the code and properly identified (add a comment such as `// <- error here:...`)

Comment: Are you sure you have correctly reproduced your includes?

Comment: `Node() : data(0)` doesn't make sense for every possible type T -- probably not your error.  The only `!=` call looks ok and there are not vectors or operator() calls.  Are you sure you don't have some other code somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are lacking the comparison operators for `std::string`. Try adding an

```
#include <string>
```

in your source file which holds `main`.

Including `<iostream>` gives you a forward declaration of `std::string`. That's because `<iostream>` allows you to do a lot of string operations (for instance, it allows you to convert a string from/to pretty much anything by using string streams). However this forward declaration does not give you any comparison operators. You need to include `<string>` for that.

For what it's worth, you could have minimized your test case to

```
#include <iostream>

bool f() {
    std::string a, b;
    return a != b;
}
```

to demonstrate this issue. This test case fails to compile for exactly the same reason, and including `<string>` makes it work.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to take a wild stab in the dark.

I think that you should `#include <string>` and not `<vector>`. You may have a forward declaration of string visible but without `<string>` I don't think that you have the correct `operator==` and `operator!=` overloads visible.